# MtGox socket.io streaming

Tags: api, socket.io, mtgox

MtGox Streaming API is down or is something wrong with the code?

I used this example https:// bitbucket.org/nitrous/mtgox-api/src/004c254993963baeb239ac7ac7f676b5024fc93f/socket/ws.client.html?at=master

You can test here http://atc.leadsoft.eu/test.html

I entered the server url (https://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox) and click connect, but most of the time it writes only Connected or Connection timeout and freezes.